# Rails, activerecord, many queries, (include?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm not clear on why in my Rails app my queries are so large, for example I have problems like this:

```
Recipe Load (4.0ms)  SELECT `recipes`.* FROM `recipes` WHERE (recipes.id > 394691) ORDER BY recipes.id LIMIT 500
 Ingredient Load (6.3ms)  SELECT `ingredients`.* FROM `ingredients` WHERE (`ingredients`.recipe_id = 394692)
 Step Load (1.7ms)  SELECT `steps`.* FROM `steps` WHERE (`steps`.recipe_id = 394692)
 Ingredient Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `ingredients`.* FROM `ingredients` WHERE (`ingredients`.recipe_id = 394693)
 Step Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `steps`.* FROM `steps` WHERE (`steps`.recipe_id = 394693)
 Ingredient Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `ingredients`.* FROM `ingredients` WHERE (`ingredients`.recipe_id = 394694)
 Step Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `steps`.* FROM `steps` WHERE (`steps`.recipe_id = 394694)
 Ingredient Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `ingredients`.* FROM `ingredients` WHERE (`ingredients`.recipe_id = 394695)
 Step Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `steps`.* FROM `steps` WHERE (`steps`.recipe_id = 394695)
 Ingredient Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `ingredients`.* FROM `ingredients` WHERE (`ingredients`.recipe_id = 394696)
 Step Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `steps`.* FROM `steps` WHERE (`steps`.recipe_id = 394696)
 Ingredient Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `ingredients`.* FROM `ingredients` WHERE (`ingredients`.recipe_id = 394697)
 Step Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `steps`.* FROM `steps` WHERE (`steps`.recipe_id = 394697)
 Ingredient Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `ingredients`.* FROM `ingredients` WHERE (`ingredients`.recipe_id = 394698)
 Step Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `steps`.* FROM `steps` WHERE (`steps`.recipe_id = 394698)
 Ingredient Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `ingredients`.* FROM `ingredients` WHERE (`ingredients`.recipe_id = 394699)
[... goes on for like 20 more rows ...]
```

Why are are there so many queries, do I need to use `:include` or something, I'm just not sure where to go with this.

Comment: Could you post the relevant source code and relations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

It looks like you probably want

```
@recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id], :include => :ingredients))
```

Comment: Its really confusing, I'm using Sunspot(solr gem for rails), and I feel like it has something to do with my nested blocks for search... not sure, thanks for your help so far, its helping me get there.